# Using awk as excel

Tags: awk

We have to process a lot of *.cvs files (almost 1 GB and 2 million rows). Everybody uses to import this files into excel and then make diverse calculations (including pivot tables)

I am trying to make these calculations using awk (maybe I will try later if is possible something similar to a pivot table) but I am finding some problems

My File is 24 columns, with ";"separator and looks like this:

```
URU;CMEX-CRI-URURTRDW01;CMEX-CRI-OCCRTRDW01;30/09/2017;23:15;3,90;0,00;0,00;1,00;1,00;9,40;37,56;URU;8000;8000;45;95;150;5;10;15;10;20;30;
URU;CMEX-CRI-URURTRDW01;CMEX-CRI-OCCRTRDW01;30/09/2017;23:20;3,80;0,00;0,00;1,00;1,00;10,36;21,69;URU;8000;8000;45;95;150;5;10;15;10;20;30;
URU;CMEX-CRI-URURTRDW01;CMEX-CRI-OCCRTRDW01;30/09/2017;23:25;3,40;0,00;1,00;1,00;1,00;73,25;41,48;URU;8000;8000;45;95;150;5;10;15;10;20;30;
URU;CMEX-CRI-URURTRDW01;CMEX-CRI-OCCRTRDW01;30/09/2017;23:30;3,45;0,00;0,00;1,00;1,00;6,06;25,10;URU;8000;8000;45;95;150;5;10;15;10;20;30;
URU;CMEX-CRI-URURTRDW01;CMEX-CRI-OCCRTRDW01;30/09/2017;23:35;3,30;0,00;0,00;1,00;1,00;8,41;37,85;URU;8000;8000;45;95;150;5;10;15;10;20;30;
URU;CMEX-CRI-URURTRDW01;CMEX-CRI-OCCRTRDW01;30/09/2017;23:40;3,30;0,00;1,00;1,00;1,00;79,05;29,61;URU;8000;8000;45;95;150;5;10;15;10;20;30;
URU;CMEX-CRI-URURTRDW01;CMEX-CRI-OCCRTRDW01;30/09/2017;23:45;3,15;0,00;1,00;0,00;1,00;6,08;62,84;URU;8000;8000;45;95;150;5;10;15;10;20;30;
URU;CMEX-CRI-URURTRDW01;CMEX-CRI-OCCRTRDW01;30/09/2017;23:50;3,80;0,00;1,17;1,00;1,13;19,05;53,19;URU;8000;8000;45;95;150;5;10;15;10;20;30;
URU;CMEX-CRI-URURTRDW01;CMEX-CRI-OCCRTRDW01;30/09/2017;23:55;4,10;0,00;1,00;1,00;1,00;83,33;24,28;URU;8000;8000;45;95;150;5;10;15;10;20;30;
```

I will love to add some new fields as a result of calculations between the prior ones

Is something like that:

```
if $8=="-1,00" OR $9=="-1,00" then $25=="-1,00"; else $25=(($8+$9)/2)
if $11 > $14 OR $12 > $15 then $26="0,00" and $27="0,00";
else if ($6 <  $16) $26="0,00"; 
else if ($6 < $17) $26="1,25"; 
else if ($6 < $18) $26="2,50"; 
else $26="5,00";
if $7 <  $19 then $27="0,00"; 
else if ($7 < $20) then $27="1,25"; 
else if ($7 < $21) $27="2,50"; 
else $27="5,00"
```

And then print all this new field after the last one

So I build this (so sorry for the structure, I am not familiar with programming, I am very sure there are a lot of codes more efficient) in one line

```
awk  '{if($8=="-1,00" || $9=="-1,00") $25=="-1,00" ; 
else $25=(($8+$9)/2)}
{if($11 > $14 || $12 > $15) $26="0,00" && $27="0,00"; 
else if ($6 <  $16) $26="0,00"; 
else if ($6 < $17) $26="1,25"; else if ($6 < $18) $26="2,50"; else $26="5,00"} 
{if ($7 <  $19) $27="0,00"; 
else if ($7 < $20) $27="1,25"; 
else if ($7 < $21) $27="2,50"; 
else $27="5,00"} {print ($0,$25,$26,$27) > "test.csv"}' FS=";" OFS=";" FILE
```

My surprise is that instead a line of 27 fields I am having lines of 30 fields ???

And ($8+$9)/2) gives no decimal...

Here is an output (may not be coincident with the lines above)

```
URU;CMEX-CRI-URURTRDW01;CMEX-CRI-OCCRTRDW01;30/09/2017;23:50;3,80;0,00;1,17;1,00;1,13;19,05;53,19;URU;8000;8000;45;95;150;5;10;15;10;20;30;1;0,00;0,00;1;0,00;0,00
URU;CMEX-CRI-URURTRDW01;CMEX-CRI-OCCRTRDW01;30/09/2017;23:55;4,10;0,00;1,00;1,00;1,00;83,33;24,28;URU;8000;8000;45;95;150;5;10;15;10;20;30;1;1;0,00;1;1;0,00
```

Anyone can help me?

I am aware that I could do that with MySQL or similar, but with awk I can  run this on my mac without any aditional installation.

Thank you for your time and help!!

Comment: it would help to have a [mcve]. That is, something easier to understand and parse

Comment: Maybe do yourself a favor and use Python and Pandas for this.  The code would be a lot easier to understand.

Comment: Demonstrate your problem with 4 or 5 lines of input, each containing 4 or 5 fields, and code that shows a couple of comparisons/assignments/prints instead of 20 or so. Make sure to post THE output you'd expect to get from THE input you posted (saying the output you post "may not be coincident" with the input you post is not acceptable). The briefer, simpler and clearer you can make your question the more people will be willing to read it as the less time they'll have to spend trying to understand it. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: @John, sorry I don´t know Python, Pandas, even VisualBasic...my fault

Answer (score 0):

Instead of referring to your calculation output in the field syntax like `$25` and the like, instead stick them in variables. Then print the variables along side your row:

```
awk  '{if($8=="-1,00" || $9=="-1,00") calc1=="-1,00" ; 
else calc1=(($8+$9)/2)}
{if($11 > $14 || $12 > $15) calc2="0,00" && calc3="0,00"; 
else if ($6 <  $16) calc2="0,00"; 
else if ($6 < $17) calc2="1,25"; else if ($6 < $18) calc2="2,50"; else calc2="5,00"} 
{if ($7 <  $19) calc3="0,00"; 
else if ($7 < $20) calc3="1,25"; 
else if ($7 < $21) calc3="2,50"; 
else calc3="5,00"} {print ($0,calc1,calc2,calc3) > "test.csv"}' FS=";" OFS=";" FILE
```

As for the pivot usecase, I think some light pivotting in awk would be reasonable, but I wouldn't expect miracles. Definitely invest some time into learning arrays and for loops to help pull it off.

Comment: Thanks @JNevill for taking your time to answer.  The new fields calc1, calc2, calc3 are been printing at the beginning of the line (makes no sense I know). But that happened in my firsts trials, so let me try again and again. Thanks a lot !!! Many thanks

Comment: `calc1=="-1,00"` in the first line is almost certainly not the intention, is it?

Comment: @PedroS, check that your input file does not have CRLF line endings. If it does, use `dos2unix` on the input file.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I agree. That should def be a single `=`. Also the `&&` in the third line is probably incorrect and should be changed to {calc2="0,00";calc3="0,00"}`. This whole thing could be rewritten to be a bit cleaner, but I really just wanted to share the concept of variables for OP to get a little closer to their goal.

Comment: Hi @JNevill. I Don't know why, but                                                           
    {print ($0,calc1,calc2,calc3) > "test.csv"} is adding a ˆM at the end of the line, so calc1, calc2 and calc3 are not the end of a line, but the beginning of another one. Just in case FILE does not have an ˆM (I've checked)

Comment: @Benjamin W, yes It's the intention, case of $8 or $9 are equal to -1, calc1 ($25) needs to be -1.  These file is about networks latency and in case some of this particular variables is -1, the global variable has to be -1

Comment: The point is that `calc1=="-1,00"` is a comparison, not an assignment.

Comment: @PedroS It's the double equal that Benjamin is pointing out. `a==`b is a condition "Is a equal to be?" where the single equal `a=b` is setting the value of `a` to the value of `b`

Comment: @JNevill, understood. So, calc1="-1".  I am following your comments, and trying as fast as I can. Thx

Answer (score 0):

When your input record (line) has 25 fields (albeit $25 is empty) and you assign to $26 and $27 as well as $25, $0 is implicitly expanded to 27 fields. When you `print $0,$25,$26,$27` it prints the 27 fields that are now in $0 and then prints $25 $26 $27 *again*. Note in your sample output that fields 28-30 are an exact copy of fields 25-27. Just print $0.

($8+$9)/2 prints with no decimals if it is an integer value. awk actually calcluates in floating-point (except very recent gawk with bignums enabled) but since people very often are actually computing with integer values, when a numeric result is an integer awk prints it with no decimals. Moreover, some awks do not support decimal comma (instead of point) on input data, so when input $8=1,17 and $9=1,00 the formula ($8+$9)/2 actually converts both $8 and $9 to 1 ignoring the decimal part just like it would convert 1abc and 1%@ to 1 ignoring the extraneous characters, then (1+1)/2 = 1, which displays as 1. GNU awk (gawk) does this by default, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121000/gawk-summing-floats-formatted-with-comma-separator , but AIUI MacOSX standard awk is not gawk so I don't know exactly if or when it honors decimal comma. However, several of your sample lines have 1,00 1,00 which even when interpreted correctly produces an integer result, so if you want to display that with ,00 (or .00 depending on locale) use `sprintf("%.2f", ($8+$9)/2)`

Comment: Thank you @dave_thompson_085. Print ($0) worked exactly as you said. I did not know that assigning a new field it was automatically appended to the line. I've also tried sprintf("%.2f", ($8+$9)/2)  in that way $25=sprintf("%.2f",($8+$9)/2)  but although it gives 2 decimals, the calculation is not correct. Taking 1,15 and 1,00 the result must be 1,07 but it gives 1,00 as result. Should I do something with the columns $8 ans $9 before the calculation? Thank You!

Comment: Making some testes, now I know that should use "." instead "," With "." the operation gives the correct answer. Thank You for your help!!